# Button inside DataGrid wpf MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mvvm, datagrid

I am following MVVM in this project.

I have WPF datagrid,

ItemsSource `(ItemsSource="{Binding Documents}")` binded to an `ObservableCollection<Document>`,

SelectedItem `(SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentDocument, Mode=TwoWay}")` binded to `WorkQueueDocument`,

I also have used Interaction Triggers to capture the Double click of the mouse - in order to load the selected Document in a New WIndow.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ShowViewerCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

I Have defined/binded the columns of my datagrid to corresponding attibutes of WorkQueueDocument class.

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto"
                            MinWidth="100"
                            Header="Name"                                                            
                            Binding="{Binding Name}">
        <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,0,0,0" />
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Name}" />
            </Style>
        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    </DataGridTextColumn>

    <!-- Many Other Columns Here... -->
</DataGrid.Columns>

<DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <!-- I have various designer style's properties defined here -->
</DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
```

---

I am supposed to load the document when the user selects the row (document) in the grid - for that CurrentDocument property is defined as follows:

```
public WorkQueueDocument CurrentDocument
{
    get
    {
        return this.currentDocument;
    }
    set
    {

        if (this.currentDocument != value)
        {
            this.currentDocument = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("CurrentDocument");
            this.IsDocumentSelected = true;

    // If we are in progress already, don't do anything
            if (!IsLoading && this.currentDocument != null)
            {
                IsLoading = true;
                LoadDocumentBackgroundWorker();// loading documenting async
            }


            if (this.currentDocument == null)
            {
                this.IsDocumentSelected = false;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Now, the problem is - I want to add a Delete Button column to this datagrid, such that when user presses Delete button - the document gets deleted directly without loading the document.
I added following xaml to `<DataGrid.Columns>`

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
    <Button Name="DeleteBatch" 
            Content="Delete"
            Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.DeleteCommand}"
            CommandParameter="Delete"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

This `DeleteCommand` ain't getting fired. I tried to figure out WHY and discovered that I have

1st command is in datagrid for loading document on selection of row

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Documents}"
```

2nd command is on delete button which is in coluumn of above datagrid

```
<Button Name="Delete" 
Content="Delete" 
Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.DeleteCommand}" 
CommandParameter="Delete">
```

, I am able to access only one command at a time. When i click the button - the row ('*obviously*') gets selected and executed associated binding for '**SelectedItem**' but does not follow up calling the

**DeleteCommand** ( which ideally should ) . But if I remove this '**SelectedItem**' property - the deleteCommand gets triggered ( but then i dont get the selected row).

**Also (while debugging i noticed) the **DeleteCommand** gets executed on when we press(click) second time (coz now the row is already selected)**

I googled - and found few *probable* solutions, like Priority Binding and Tunneling , but unable to implement.
Please guide me through this.

I got this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/441ff41a-6759-4dd5-b8b6-c6f8e200ba89/attached-dependencyobject-to-datagrid-previewkey-event) , but not sure if this is the only way.

P.S :
1. I am using WPF , .Net 4.0 and MVVM

2. Please do not suggest Third Party solutions. [unless the only option]

Comment: A workaround could be to have a button for loading the document instead of clicking the row

Comment: Thanks @Shoe , but the design doesn't permit that. :)

Comment: Try putting the delete button in `RowHeaderTemplate` and see what happens.

Answer (score 5):

- The delete command parameter should just be

  `CommandParameter="{Binding}"`
- this means that the command parameter is the document reference
  itself thus you can do the following in your command

  yourDocumentObservableCollection.Remove(CommandParameter)

This way you wont need to care about if the Document is focused or not.

Comment: I completely agree with you , but the real Problem is I am not able to trigger the DeleteCommand the very first time. When i click the DeleteButton, first time, only the 'CurrentDocument' property gets executed ( which loads the Doc ) and DOESNOT call DeleteCommand , while on second press it DOES . Thanks for your help .

Comment: @Bhramar normally the document doesn't have to be focused for the command to execute unless your CanExecute requires that, i did it with both GridControl and ListBox, both had almost the same behavior, items get deleted without the row being selected.